# Linear Combination of Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

$\xi_{1}, \ldots, \xi_{5}$ and independent random variables with $N_{1,4}$ distribution. Find distribution of

$\eta = \xi_{1}-\frac{\xi_{2}+\xi_{3}+\xi_{4}+\xi_{5}}{2}$

and its CDF.

**My solution**

We know that if $X \in N_{a,\alpha^2}$ and $Y \in N_{b,\beta^2}$ then $X+Y=Z \in N_{a+b,\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$

Also, $X=cZ \in N_{a,(c\alpha)^2}$, where $c =const$

So,

$\eta \in N_{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right), 4-(1+1+1+1)} = N_{0,0}$

Basically, I get Dirac delta function which is weird (or not?). Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables then $var (X-Y)=var (X)+var (Y)$, not $var (X-Y)=var (X)-var (Y)$.